# tufte-book and arabic text (bidi problem?)

Tags: polyglossia, tufte, arabic, bidi, arabxetex

I am typesetting a `tufte-book` document with XeLaTeX that has both English and Arabic text.  The Tufte-style title pages consistently break, whether I use the package `arabxetext` or `polyglossia`.  I suspect a clash with the underlying `bidi` package.

Here is a minimal example with `arabxetex`:

```
\documentclass[nols,justified]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{arabxetex}
\title{Some Book}
\author[Series]{\textit{ John Doe}}
\publisher{World Publisher}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Foo Bar}
\begin{arab}
بعد هامش وإقامة المتحدة و، أم السادس وبالرغم فقد.
\end{arab}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Here is the minimal example with `polyglossia`:

```
\documentclass[nols,justified]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5] {Amiri Quran}
\title{Some Book}
\author[Series]{\textit{ John Doe}}
\publisher{World Publisher}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
\section{New Section}
\begin{Arabic}
بعد هامش وإقامة المتحدة و، أم السادس وبالرغم فقد.     
\end{Arabic}  

\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Both give the following errors:

```
LaTeX Error: Command \XeTeX already defined.
XeLaTeX Error: Command \XeTeX already defined.
```

Is there a solution for using mixed English/Arabic text with the `tufte-book` document class?
I have tried the biditufte class, but find that is designed for RTL text.

The title page compiles incorrectly.  The following example demonstrates what the title page should look like:

```
\documentclass[nols,justified]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Some Book}
\author[Series]{\textit{John Doe}}
\publisher{World Publisher}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Foo Bar}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's easy: see below!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Haha!

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[nols,justified]{biditufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5] {Amiri Quran}
\title{Some Book}
\author[Series]{\textit{ John Doe}}
\publisher{World Publisher}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
\section{New Section}
\begin{Arabic}
بعد هامش وإقامة المتحدة و، أم السادس وبالرغم فقد.     
\end{Arabic}  

\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message: `LaTeX Error: Command \XeTeX already defined.` and XeLaTeX Error: Command \XeTeX already defined.`

Comment: As well,  the title and pages are all shifted toward the margin.  I have compiled with `biditufte` on overleaf.com with the same result, so I don't believe the problem is my configuration.  Do you have the same result?

Comment: No, I don't.  Everything looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

`\documentclass[nols,justified]{biditufte-book}` does solve the problem, however the option `[LTRgeometry]` is needed if the document is primarily written in a left-to-right language like English.  The `[justified]` option is also unnecessary with the `biditufte-book` class.  Partial documentation for the `biditufte-book` document class book is found in the `bidi` documentation.

Comment: Good comment....