# tufte-book & Tectonic (XeTeX) & bidi / polyglossia don't get along

Tags: polyglossia, tufte, bidi

I'm trying to write a document with tufte-book. Most of the document is supposed to be in English but I wish to write some text in Hebrew. I am able successfully compile documents with more common document classes with polyglossia and [Tectonic](https://tectonic-typesetting.github.io/) which internally uses XeTeX. But with tufte-book and this MWE:

```tex
%! TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[nols,nobib,bidi]{tufte-book}
% Language
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\begin{document}

Hello World.

\end{document}
```

I get this weird error:

```
****************************************************
(biditools.sty) (zref-abspage.sty (zref-base.sty)) (latex-xetex-bidi.def

! LaTeX Error: Command \XeTeX already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.138 ...di@reflect@box{E}}\kern-.1667em \TeX}}$}}
```

I'm using tufte-book from it's Git repository. Is this a polyglossia bug or a tufte bug? I'd also like to know what use can I find for the `bidi` option in `tufte-book` `\documentclass`.

Lastly, [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355014/tufte-book-and-arabic-text-bidi-problem) suggests to use `biditufte-book` class provided by the `bidi` package but I can't use it since I'd like to use `biblatex` and `biditufte-book` doesn't support the `nobib` option [which I need](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/587605/tufte-book-biblatex-error-biblatex-incompatible-with-natbib).

Comment: The `tufte` suite should be updated not to load `xltxtra`. This package loads `metalogo` and this is the problem, because `bidi` doesn't check whether `\XeTeX` and `\XeLaTeX` are already defined (which is also wrong). Just add `\let\XeTeX\relax` and `\let\XeLaTeX\relax` before `\usepackage{polyglossia}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a combined problem.

The `tufte-book.cls` loads `tufte-common.def` that, when XeLaTeX as processing engine is detected, does `\RequirePackage{xltxtra}`, which used to be recommended several years ago, but now it's definitely recommended *not* to load it.

What happens? That `xltxtra` loads `metalogo`, which defines the commands `\XeTeX` and `\XeLaTeX.

Later, `bidi` does an unconditional definition of both commands, without any check on whether they're already defined, which is obviously wrong. It should first remove possible definitions of the commands, and then add its own adaptation for bidirectional typesetting.

Fix:

```
%! TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[nols,nobib,bidi]{tufte-book}

% fix the bad interaction
\let\XeTeX\undefined
\let\XeLaTeX\undefined

% Language
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}

\begin{document}

Hello World.

\end{document}
```