# Why is this command form tufte-book class does not compile

Tags: pdftex, xetex, tufte-book

I don't know why when I compile my project with xelatex this command gives me an error and is not showing in pdf.

The command is the `openepigraph` command:

```
\newcommand{\openepigraph}[2]{%
  %\sffamily\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont
  \begin{fullwidth}
  %\sffamily\large
  \begin{doublespace}
  \noindent\allcaps{#1}\\% epigraph
  \noindent\allcaps{#2}% author
  \end{doublespace}
  \end{fullwidth}
}
```

Here is an example:

```
\openepigraph{En este capítulo veremos los tipos de enlace entre átomos, concepto de cristal, redes de Bravais, concepto de base, planos y direcciones cristalinas, estructuras relevantes.}{GUÍA}
```

This are the errors that gives me:

[image]

I didn't make this command, I copied form an Overleaf sheet and I don't know why in pdflatex works but in xeltaxe or lualatex doesn't.

Thanks for reading

Comment: please provide an example and also say exactly what error you got

Comment: @DavidCarlisle done

Comment: Fixed with this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/587625/tufte-book-tectonic-xetex-bidi-polyglossia-dont-get-along

Comment: no, by an example  I meant a test document we could run to debug, but glad you got it sorted, we can close as duplicate then